Witch paints uncle/father he disappears, traps him in painting YA book read 40 years ago
Trying to find fantasy book I read as a child, was a bit scary, sort of mild YA horror. Main thing I remember was these children had an aunt or stepmother or governess who was some kind of witch. The uncle, or father, can’t remember which, disappeared and at some point the kids realise she had put him actually into a painting. He had a horrified look on his face.
I think no one believed them or something?? Was a long time ago. I would have read it circa 1980.
